# Database structure for non linear data

Tags: database-design

I need advise about a database structure. I need to capture data from the web about one specific subject on few specific websites and insert that data to a database.

The problem with this task is that the information is not linear, if I try to design tables with fields for all possible data I will end up with many row fields with NULL values. There are any problem with this(end up with many row fields with NULL values)? Or should I user other kind of structure? For example store the data in one field and that field containing an associative array with data.

What I mean with non linear data is the following:

```
array(
      'name' => 'Don',
      'age'  => '31'
     );


array(
      'name' => 'Peter',
      'age'  => '28',
      'car'  => 'ford',
      'km'   => '2000'
     );
```

In a specific website search I will store only "name" and "age", and in other website I will store "name", "age", "car" and "km".

I don't know If I explain weel my problem. My english is not very good.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok lets track back..and assume you are most comfortable with databases....you can always break down a nonlinear structure to linear type..only query performance will get hit..

No problem in rows with lot of null values. Depends on db implementation, but I have seen such designs before and they are pretty flexible.

Let me give an example
Lets say we have to store hours worked per week..but in your case week can have any number of days.

So you define a table with columns like

StartDate, Id, MondayHour, Tuesdayhour, etc etc..upto SundayHour 
If you want to add another hour like MondayHour1, just add the column and modify your queries..

To store the same structure is a linear(normalized) way(not sure if linear is a right word here) just define a table as follows DayID, DayName

And then your hours table will have StartDate, ID, DayID, Hours..
Only now you need a join on two tables.

Hope I have understood and  answered your question correctly

Answer (score 1):

This kind of problem is exactly the area where NoSQL solutions excell. With a traditional database you have to specify all columns in advance while NoSQL solutions give you the option of adding any kind of data you like.

So it depends on wheter you will have a fixed amount of data or not. If you already know all the columns that you'll use. Than you can add the columns as `NULL`.

If you don't know all the columns yet and expect that there will be more columns in the future, than a NoSQL solution would be better.

Answer (score 1):

You have many options,

- using database with support for objects
- --"-- with support for xml
- your solution, keeping baseinfo in one table, attributes in another.

Personally, I'd use 3), easy and fast. And doesn't tie you down to specific
db or software.

regards,
/t